# Angular FormGroup validators (Not formControl validator)

Tags: angular

As known, we can add validators to specific formControl inside formGroup and we will get the validators error (true or false) by using `controlname.errors`.

I found that i can add validators to the FormGroup itself which is not bind directly to formControl and i thought i can find the errors of that validators by using `formGroupName.errors` but this property is always null.

Can someone help with that?

Comment: You can use myForm.controls('mygroup').hasError('name_of_error`') if is a groupName, or myFom.hasError('name_of_error') if is the form itself

Comment: @Eliseo i have only one formGroup... the errors array is null.

Comment: How do you set the validators/errors?

Comment: @Alex Inside the formgroup ctor

Comment: Could you show your code for that for clarification? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add validator to the form group like this:

```
this.form = this.formbuilder.group({
<controls declared here>
    }, {validator: <your validator>});
```

You can then access the errors like this:

```
form.errors.<your_error_name>
```